# I have try to install node js 4.3.2 version but it give error

Tags: node.js

sudo apt-get install nodejs=4.3.2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.3.2' for 'nodejs' was not found

Comment: What version of Linux? Most distros don’t have packages for all arbitrary versions - you will probably need to download the source tarballs and build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically want to install version 4.*? The newest available is 12.*.

For installation of a specific version use `apt-get install package=version -V`. If this does not work for you please provide more info about your linux distro & version. You can always download the right Version of node manually on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/). You could also build it yourself.

Also check version availability for your system with `sudo apt policy nodejs`

Either way, first remove the previous installation completele, using

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

then try installing the current version with PPA, by first running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

after that you can check the version with `node -v` and for npm with `npm -v`

Comment: I'm working on the maintenance project so I need to install that version in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing NodeJS using NVM

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
```

check NVM is installed properly

```
nvm --version
```

To install the latest stable version

```
nvm install stable
```

Or a specific version

```
nvm install 12.4.0
nvm install 4
```

To list locally available Node JS versions

```
nvm list
```

Switch NodeJS version

```
nvm use version
Eg : nvm use 4
```

To make nodejs available for all users

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Or Install it manually by downloading

https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.2/node-v4.3.2-linux-x64.tar.xz

Comment: It does not work ..Do you have another solution to install node js 4.3.2 version on ubuntu

Comment: @neha-srivastava, updated the answer, check. Added the download link for Nodejs V4.3.2